# Magento upgrade 1.4.x to 1.7 error

Tags: magento-1.7, upgrade

I just updated a Magento shop from Magento 1.4.2 to 1.7.0

When I go to checkout, it gives following warning and doesn't show further page.

```
Warning: include(Mage\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Label.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93
```

Please tell me how can I fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some 3rd-party module or your custom theme is referring to `Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data_Label` class which is deprecated.

Try switching to default theme and disabling modules one by one to localise the problem.

Comment: I just added a check is_object in data.php and copied in local.

Answer (score 1):

This Problem is caused by the Payone Payment Module.
To fix it, check `eav_attribute` table in Database and change the value for column `frontend_input` from `label` to `text` (or `date´). I had to change 3 entries which attribute_code started with`customer_address_payone_*`